# iptables nat same port, multiple providers

Tags: iptables, routing, centos6

my configuration:

`# ip route sh
zzz.zzz.zzz.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src zzz.zzz.zzz.1
yyy.yyy.yyy.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src yyy.yyy.yyy.146
xxx.xxx.xx8.0/23 dev eth4  proto kernel  scope link  src xxx.xxx.xx9.47
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth3  scope link  metric 1002
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth4  scope link  metric 1003
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1004
default via xxx.xxx.xxx.1 dev eth4`

`# ip rule sh
0:      from all lookup local
217:    from xxx.xxx.xx9.47 lookup table1
219:    from yyy.yyy.yyy.146 lookup table2
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default`

`# ip ro sh table table2
zzz.zzz.zzz.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src zzz.zzz.zzz.1
yyy.yyy.yyy.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src yyy.yyy.yyy.146
default via yyy.yyy.yyy.1 dev eth1`

`# ip ro sh table table1
zzz.zzz.zzz.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src zzz.zzz.zzz.1
xxx.xxx.xx8.0/23 dev eth4  proto kernel  scope link  src xxx.xxx.xx9.47
default via xxx.xxx.xx8.1 dev eth4`

`iptables -t nat -L POSTROUTING
MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth4    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0`

rp_filter is set to 0 (tryed with 2, the same thing)

when i try to reach either xxx.xxx.xx9.47 or yyy.yyy.yyy.146 from internet they work perfect with this config.
from the lan (zzz.zzz.zzz.0/24) the internet works perfect, traffic goes out thru default route.

i forwarded a port to a computer in zzz.zzz.zzz.0/24 lan

`# iptables -t nat -L PREROUTING  -nv
DNAT       tcp  --  eth4   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:aa to:zzz.zzz.zzz.3:bb
DNAT       tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:aa to:zzz.zzz.zzz.3:bb`

from internet i can reach zzz.zzz.zzz.3 on port aa only by using xxx.xxx.xx9.47, the ip from default route.
i get connection failed from yyy.yyy.yyy.146, which is not default route.
tcpdump on the eth1 only shows incoming traffic
if i tcpdump the default route interface (this case eth4) i see the packets trying to leave the interface with source ip yyy.yyy.yyy.146 witch of course it doesn't work

if i change default route to eth1 the exact opposed thing happen.
i get responss from yyy.yyy.yyy.146 on port aa and connection failed from xxx.xxx.xx9.47
tcpdump the eth1 i see the packets trying to leave on eth1 with xxx.xxx.xx9.47 when trying to access xxx.xxx.xx9.47 on aa port

changed maquerade with snat
`# iptables -t nat -L POSTROUTING
SNAT       all  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           to:yyy.yyy.yyy.146
SNAT       all  --  *      eth4    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           to:xxx.xxx.xx9.47`

and still tcpdump on the default route shows response packages with source yyy.yyy.yyy.146 leaving eth4
so.. snat or masquerade work, contrack works. i really don't understand why it only tries to respond only on default interface, even if the source ip is from the other interface... and how come that it snat on one interface with ip from the other.
the operating system is centos 6.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When packets come in via interface X, and are responded to immediately by the same machine, then your source-based routing rule can catch the response because its source IP address will necessarily match the rule.

When these packets are subsequently forwarded via interface Y to another IP, that first part of the communication will work. But as soon as the first response packet arrives from this other IP, it will enter the routing rule parser with its own source IP address, not this router's. It will then miss the source-based routing rules, and instead match the default lookup, which will be destination-based as usual.

What you will need to do is to mark packets as they arrive on interface X, with this mark persisting across forwarding, and then match that mark in routing rules so a different outgoing routing table is used.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it needed to be done with marking packets.

I figured it out by using mangle

```
# iptables -t mangle -L PREROUTING -nv
CONNMARK   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           CONNMARK restore
MARK       all  --  eth4   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           MARK set 0xc8
MARK       all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           MARK set 0xd3
CONNMARK   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           CONNMARK save
```

Basically I mark the incoming connections on each interface and restore marker on tracked connections. So a connection marked as from eth1 will always go to rule fwmark 211(0xd3) and eth4 via rule fwmark 200 (0xc8)